# How to get Users in the Farm with JQuery

Tags: jquery, web-services, user-profile, server-farm

want to users all the Sharepoint farm, so I would like to consume SharePoint web services using javascript/jQuery. I am capable to write small scripts using javascript/jQuery, but I don't know how to consume a web sesrvice and getting results from it.

Comment: I am not sure if you can query Farm with Jquery for all users. But every site has a hidden User Information List. You can query that List for users. Only problem with this is that users who has never logged into sharepoint site will not be available in User Information List.

Comment: Ok, so what i'm trying to so is list all people that has multiple account in active directory and give them the same permission of  their first account on SP Do you Should I get them directly from AD?

Comment: You have to define what you mean b "Account". SharePoint uses AD for Authentication, so if you are saying people have more than one AD account, SharePoint cannot tell. As Amit said, there are User Profiles (usually matched to an AD account and imported, and User Info list entries in each Site Collection. I think you need to look at your AD.

Comment: It seems your right . there's a little problem.. I've been trying to get all users from sharepoint site collection site, but some people that a can retrieve using  people picker, I can't find them from the code. And whne I try to get tme using  "UserProfile user = userProfileMgr.GetUserProfile(targetAccountName)", I get the exception "An error was encountered while retrieving the user profile